# How can I move the location of ntuser files

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I am trying to use cygwin as the default terminal on Windows 7.
I have changed the home directory to my user directory.
ntuser files just fill up the prompt whenever I 'ls' with ntuser files.
Is it possible to move their location? I tried googling.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just ignoring the files by adding the follwing in .bashrc:

```
alias ls='ls -hF --color=tty --ignore=ntuser*'
```

which does a fine job.
I also added the following in .vimrc to ignore them in NERDTree:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['^ntuser\.']
```